# Salvar entidade filha em relação ManyToOne Hibernate Jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, maven

Tenho 3 entidades: Pedido, Pedido_Servico e Servico;
Existe uma relação muitos para muitos entre as entidades Pedido e Servico por isso criei a terceira tabela;

Eu gostaria de salvar um Pedido e tambem os filhos Pedido_Servico;

O que acontece é que está salvando o pedido normalmente mas não salva os filhos!

Segue exemplo do código!

Classe Serviço

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "servico")
public class Servico {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_servico")
    private long idServico;
    @Column(name = "nome_servico", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String nomeServico;
    @Column(name = "valor_hora", nullable = false)
    private double valorHora;
}
```

Classe Pedido

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido")
public class Pedido {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_pedido")
    private Long idPedido;
    @Column(name = "valor_total_bruto", nullable = false)
    private double valorTotalBruto;
    @Column(name = "valor_total_liquido", nullable = false)
    private double valorTotalLiquido;
    @Column(name = "perc_imposto", nullable = false)
    private double percentualImposto;
    @Column(name = "usuario", length = 100, nullable = false)
    private String usuario;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pedido")
    private List<PedidoServico> pedidoServicos;
}
```

Classe Pedido_Servico

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pedido_servico")
public class PedidoServico {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_pedido_servico")
    private long idPedidoServico;
    @Column(name = "qtd_hora", nullable = false)
    private int qtdHora;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_pedido")
    private Pedido pedido;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_servico")
    private Servico servico;
}
```

Dessa Forma esta salvando o Pedido e o Pedido_Serviço, o problema é que na classe "intermediária" não está salvando as Foreign key: id_servico e id_pedido!
Como posso resolver esse problema?

Sege imagem do teste!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado no banco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: em manyToMany irá ter uma tabela pivo que quando é definido no join já é criada então basta passar os dados no body https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Comment: Olá André obrigado pela resposta, dessa forma funcionaria sem problemas, no meu caso eu preciso guardar mais informações na entidade associativa alem das 2 foreign key, mas depois de muita pesquisa consegui resolver hehe :D

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver dessa forma.
Na classe Pedido a relação ficou assim:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_pedido")
private List<PedidoServico> pedidoServicos = new ArrayList<>();
```

e na classe pedido_servico fiz associação apenas para classe serviço, dessa forma:

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "id_servico", nullable = false)
private Servico servico;
```